# Anyone who has an idea about this video clip

Tags: ros, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear, ROS-users.

Recently, I could find this cool footage from CCNY-Robotics.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=XrkY1DCNQkQ

I'm just wondering how they could visualize such rainbow color laser scan data w.r.t height data.

Does Rviz support this function by default?

If I have /height /scan /map /odom topics, is it possible to visualize like the above footage?

Any idea would be appreciate.

Cheers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32485/anyone-who-has-an-idea-about-this-video-clip./) by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 177 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Coloring w.r.t height data is available for PointClouds using the PointCloud2 display in rviz. Either the axis or intensity transformers can do this if you select the "z" axis of the points (or whichever other field you'd like to colorize based on). Once selected, play with the settings for the displays until you get the view you want (e.g. turn on "Use full color spectrum" to interpolate in the full RGB space).

I don't believe rviz can do this for LaserScan messages, so you'd have to transform your LaserScans to PointCloud2's first (see [laser_pipeline](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_pipeline) for packages that will help you do this).

Update: `rviz` can actually colorize LaserScans by fixed frame axis, so you shouldn't need to transform them into PointClouds first.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-04-25**:
No, it can color laser scan messages along an axis.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could generate 2.5D map simply subscribing height message and put it into base_link tf.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=UUUMq8_xIORNn1P_jkQ58vKQ&feature=player_detailpage&v=JoIcV92jEWc

Also, rviz provides colorized visualization for specified axis.

This is my vcg file.

```
    Background\ ColorR=0
  2 Background\ ColorG=0
  3 Background\ ColorB=0
  4 Fixed\ Frame=/map
  5 Target\ Frame=<Fixed Frame>
  6 Grid.Alpha=0.2
  7 Grid.Cell\ Size=1
  8 Grid.ColorR=1
  9 Grid.ColorG=1
 10 Grid.ColorB=1
 11 Grid.Enabled=1
 12 Grid.Line\ Style=0
 13 Grid.Line\ Width=0.03
 14 Grid.Normal\ Cell\ Count=0
 15 Grid.OffsetX=0
 16 Grid.OffsetY=0
 17 Grid.OffsetZ=0
 18 Grid.Plane=0
 19 Grid.Plane\ Cell\ Count=80
 20 Grid.Reference\ Frame=<Fixed Frame>
 21 Laser\ Scan.Alpha=1
 22 Laser\ Scan.Billboard\ Size=0.01
 23 Laser\ Scan.Color\ Transformer=Axis
 24 Laser\ Scan.Decay\ Time=100
 25 Laser\ Scan.Enabled=1
 26 Laser\ Scan.Position\ Transformer=XYZ
 27 Laser\ Scan.Selectable=1
 28 Laser\ Scan.Style=0
 29 Laser\ Scan.Topic=/scan
```

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) with karma: 177 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-07-01**:
Hi there! May I know how do I subscribe height message and put it into base_link?